# MongoDB Compass Import CSV UTF-8 characters not recognized even if excel shows correctly

Tags: mongodb, csv, utf-8, import, compass

I'm trying to import a CSV into a MongoDB collection using the Compass tool. The import is successful but I have special characters such as german umlauts that are marked with a question mark. The CSV is an export from excel.

I Saved As CSV and selected in Tools->Web the encoding as UTF-8. This didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I have an update: I managed to find a workaround by pasting (not opening) the CSV data in Notepad++ and manually changing the encoding to UTF-8 and then saving the file.
For me it this is enough since I had a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Open your excel file:
`File > Save as > CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)`

DO NOT CHOOSE  `CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)`

CHOOSE `CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Right Click your exported CSV file and choose **"Edit in Notepad"**.

**Step 2**: Click on **"File"** menu and choose **"Save as"**

**Step 3**: In **"Save as type"** dropdown choose **"All files"**

**Step 4**: In **"File name"** text box type the file name(may be same or different) with extension **".csv"**

**Step 5** : In the Encoding dropdown at bottom choose **"UTF-8 with BOM"** and click on **"Save"** button

***Its done now. Open the csv file excel and check.***